# Let $x_0 \geq 2$ and $x_{n+1}=2+\sqrt{x_n-2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\{x_n\}_n$ is convergent.

Tags: analysis

I assume to show that this is convergent that I should use the monotone convergence theorem somehow, but I think what confuses me most is $x_{n+1}=2+\sqrt{x_n-2}$.  I think that $x_1 \geq 2$, since $x_0 \geq 2$, but I am kind of lost.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=x_n-2$, then $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n}$$
are non-negative by induction. Moreover $a_n=a_0^{1/2^n}$, thus

1. If $a_0=0$, $a_n=0$ for all $n$.
2. If $a_0>0$, $a_n\to 1$.